# Position fixed changes container width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to prevent the header element from scrolling, so I gave it `position: fixed` but that changes it size as per the second image below.
I am after a css to maintain the look of the first image and prevent the header from scrolling. Thanks

[image]

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

button {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 0;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 5em);
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body >
<header>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >&#9776;</button>
    <label>Title of Page</label>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">&#8942;</button>
</header>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `width:100%` to header element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just give `width:100%` to header.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

button {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 0;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 5em);
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body >
<header>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >&#9776;</button>
    <label>Title of Page</label>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">&#8942;</button>
</header>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply add `width:100%;` to the `header`, like the following solution:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
button {
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  top: 0;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 5em);
  text-align: center;
}
header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  </head>
  <body >
    <header>
      <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >&#9776;</button>
      <label>Title of Page</label>
      <button class="menuRight" type="button">&#8942;</button>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `width:100%;` in the `.header` .You can see working demo in [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/djc10L3y/)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
button {
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  top: 0;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 5em);
  text-align: center;
}
header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <button class="menuLeft" type="button">&#9776;</button>
  <label>Title of Page</label>
  <button class="menuRight" type="button">&#8942;</button>
</header>
```